# Undefined name 'Colors'. when using TextStyle class in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, colors

I'm new to flutter,
I'm getting an error Undefined name 'Colors'. when using Colors. in TextStyle class

```
Widget nameCode() => Expanded(
  flex: 1,
  child: Center(
    child: Text(
      'GAIN',
      style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.blue),
    ),
  ),
);
```

[image: Error shows in IDE]

Answer (score 5):

Please, make sure you have included:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```